# Scheme: what is the intuition for COND to support multiple expressions in its body?

Tags: scheme, lisp

All of the following are correct. But versoin 2 seems a bit confusing as it suggests an order/sequence of execution, which I think is discouraged in functional progrmaming. So I wonder what is the intuition/benifit of allowing version 2. Is it just for simpler code than versoin 3?

```
; version 1
(define (foo x)
  (cond ((> x 0) 1)))

; version 2
(define (foo x)
  (cond ((> x 0) 1 2 3)))

; version 3
(define (foo x)
  (cond ((> x 0)
         (begin 1 2 3))))
```

Comment: Version 2 and 3 are _exactly_ the same, it's just that in version 2 the `begin` is implicit.

Comment: Why are you worrying about `cond`: if you want to worry, worry about why *`lambda`* supports multiple expressions.

Comment: @tfb Why would you write multiple expressions in a lambda expression in the first place? But that's irrelevant anyway. I was asking why the designers of Scheme allow both version 2 and version 3 to exist, instead of one only (preferably version 3). And it seems you didn't answer that at all :(

Comment: @wlnirvana: well, why did they not require you to write `(define (x ...) (begin ... ...))` instead of `(define (x) ... ...)`, as I said?  Because its a complete pain is why, and implicit-`progn` (or implicit-`begin` in Scheme terms) makes the language actually usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheme isn't a functional language, let alone a non-strictly evaluated one. Scheme directly provides sequenced evaluation of forms. The `cond` form itself isn't strictly functional: it evaluates the test clauses in strict order, and when it finds one which yields true, it skips the remaining ones. So even without using multiple forms in a single `cond` clause, we can express imperative programming:

```
(cond
  ((> x 10)
   (set! y 3))
  ((< x 0)
   (set! z 5)))
```

The `cond` form has a long history in Lisp. It was present in some of the earliest versions of Lisp and is described in the 1960 Lisp 1 manual. In that manual, the `cond` which is described in fact doesn't allow multiple forms: it arguments are strict pairs. It is still that way in the Lisp 1.5 manual. At some point, Lisp dialects started exhibiting the multiple-forms support in `cond` clauses. Curiously, though, the "cond pair" terminology refuses to die.

The intuition behind allowing `(cond (test1 e1 e2 .. en))` is that if you do not provide this, the programmer will get the desired behavior anyway, at the cost of extra verbiage, as your example shows with the explicit `begin`: another level of parenthesis nesting accompanied by an operator symbol.

It is a backward-compatible extension to the original `cond`. Allowing the extra forms doesn't change the meaning of `cond` expressions that were previously correct; it adds meaning to `cond` expressions that were previously ill-formed.

Other dialects of Lisp, such as Common Lisp and Emacs Lisp, have multiple form evaluation in their `cond` clauses, so not allowing it in Scheme would only reduce compatibility, adding to someone's workload when they convert code from another dialect to Scheme.

Answer (score 2):

It is not only discouraged, but pointless, for functional programming (either of version 2 or 3).  But it is useful if you need to produce side-effects (for example, printing), and version 2 is a bit simpler than version 3.

Comment: @wlnirvana - remember that Lisp and Scheme are general-purpose languages that _allow, but do not enforce_ functional programming. If you want to do pure FP in a Lisp, it is up to you to enforce pure FP constraints. Fortunately Lisp is "the programmable programming language", so you can do that enforcing in Lisp if you want to.